# How to define own child element type in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to implement the following **tabs** sample as react components by using typescript;

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

I am in the development process right now and it is going well but I just have a question about the child prop types.

I have a template to create a tab menu like;

```
   <Tabs>
    <Tab tabId="home" title="Home">
      <h6>Home page content</h6>
    </Tab>
    <Tab tabId="settings" title="Settings">
      <h6>Settings page content</h6>
    </Tab>
    <Tab tabId="profile" title="Profile">
      <h1>Profile page content</h1>
    </Tab>
   </Tabs>
```

**Tabs** component should get a single or more **Tab** components and I have declared this in the TabsProps. In the current state, I defined the child element as **JSX.Element** and parsed these elements like the following;

TabsProps;

```
export interface TabsProps {
  /**
   * Tab contents
   */
  children?: JSX.Element[]
}
```

Tabs component Render;

```
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="tab">
        {
          children?.map((tab: JSX.Element) => {
            let title = tab.props.title
            let tabId = tab.props.tabId
            return <button key={tabId} className="tablinks" onClick={(event) => onButtonClicked(tabId, event.target)}>{title}</button>
          })

        }
      </div>
      {
        children?.map((tab: JSX.Element) => {
          let tabId = tab.props.tabId
          return (
            <div key={tabId} id={tabId} className="tabcontent">
                {tab.props.children}
            </div>)
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
```

Also my tab.js file;

```
export interface TabProps {
  /**
   * Unique tab id
   */
  tabId: String;
  /**
   * Tab title
   */
  title: String;
  /**
   * Tab contents
   */
  children: JSX.Element
}

/**
 * Primary tab element to wrap tab contents
 */
const Tab: React.FC<TabProps> = (props) => {
  return <h1>test</h1>
};

export default Tab;
```

Now I am asking the main question. The children object type is **JSX.Element** array type but I think it should be a type that contains the title and tabId elements in the props. In the current state, I can type `let title = tab.props.abc` instead of `let title = tab.props.title` and there won't be any problem till the runtime. How can I handle this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just create a Tab type? `type Tab { title:string; tabId: number }`

Comment: I suggest reading over the React docs on the topic: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-props-to-a-component#passing-jsx-as-children

Answer (score 0):

I could handle this by using `React.ReactElement<TabProps>` instead of `JSX.Element[]`.

```
export interface TabsProps {
  /**
   * Tab contents
   */
  children?: React.ReactElement<TabProps>[]
}
```